# Why can't I use BindingList<TInherited> as a parameter to a method that takes BindingList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, ienumerable, bindinglist

Basically I have a method with the following signature:

```
public void Save(BindingList<T> items);
```

and I'm trying to call it using

```
classInstance.Save(items); //items = BindingList<ObjectInheritedFromT>
```

but it seems that C# doesn't realize the inheritance throwing a compile-time error, where all code written for `T` would be completely functional for `ObjectInheritedFromT` as well, wouldn't it?.

Is there a work around for this? I realized this works if it were `IEnumerable`, but then (oddly enough) it turns out `BindingList<>` doesn't implement IEnumerable, and I need to perform operations such as `Remove` and `Add`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `BindingList<T>` isn't declared as `BindingList<out T>` - it doesn't support covariance

Give this a read:

[Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Comment: I read about it a while ago and now that you mention it I remembered. Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: You could `.Cast<T>` it, or otherwise mangle it to the expected type, but no, there's no workaround that'll affect `BindingList<T>` itself.